# JavaScript carregar PartialView passando uma Model

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Preciso chamar uma PartialView em meu JavaScript porém não estou sabendo como.

Estou utilizando um plugin que na variável TARGET recebe uma Div. E essa no meu caso, essa Div eu coloquei sendo uma Partial View. Meu JS está assim:

```
    var modal = new Custombox.modal({
        content: {
            effect: 'blur',
            target: '#MinhaDiv',
            }
        }).open();
```

A idéia seria fazer algo próximo disso:

```
var modal = new Custombox.modal({
        content: {
            effect: 'blur',
            target: @Html.Partial("_Unidade", Model),
            }
        }).open();
```

Claro que este exemplo não vai rodar pq estou utilizando o helper dentro do JavaScript. Mas o exemplo é para transmitir a minha necessidade.

> Portanto preciso que o JavaScript carregue uma PartialView e ainda
>   passe uma model para ela. Isso é possível?

Comment: Sim é possivel, mas, deveria ser assim, ao carregar a sua página que contem essa `div` já carregar a partial direto para ele, e após você chamar via javascript a mesma já estava pronta para ser utilizada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto não vai funcionar:

```
var modal = new Custombox.modal({
    content: {
        effect: 'blur',
        target: @Html.Partial("_Unidade", Model),
        }
    }).open();
```

Você precisa chamar `@Html.Partial` antes da declaração do JavaScript. Se a declaração do JavaScript precisa de dados da *View* para funcionar, ela deve ser montada em *View* usando `@section Scripts {}` ao final da *View*:

```
@Html.Partial("_Unidade", Model)

@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        var modal = new Custombox.modal({
            content: {
                effect: 'blur',
                target: '#MinhaDiv',
            }
        }).open();
    </script>
}
```

Estou supondo que há esta declaração no seu `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```